# Haskell IO function accepting return value from a another function

Tags: haskell, input

```
module PRO where
average1 :: IO Float
avarage1  =
    do
        putStrLn "Enter Marks in Form of a List"
        marks <- getLine
        let m = (read marks)::[Int]
        x<-(sum' (m)) 
        avg <- x/length (m)
        if(x/=[])
           then
                putStrLn ("empty List")
            else
                putStrLn ("Your Avarage is " ++ show(avg))


sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

My program doesn't seems to work! My question is why can't I assign `avg` the returning `sum` of the `sum'` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `<-` notation for assigning the return values of `sum' m` and `x/length m`.  `<-` can only be used when the right-hand side is a monadic expression (in this case, an `IO` value), which neither one is, and so you should use `let x = sum' m` and `let avg = x / fromInteger (length m)` instead (`fromInteger` is needed to convert the `Int` returned by `length m` to a Fractional value so it can be passed to `/`).  (Also, you need to change `x /= []` to `m /= []`.)

Comment: thanx jwodder! but i still can not let calculate the average i getting error

    ERROR file:.\PRO.hs:10 - Type error in application
    *** Expression     : fromInteger (length m)
    *** Term           : length m
    *** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : Integer

Comment: @visuddha use `fromIntegral` to coerce integral types.

Answer (score 6):

```
module PRO where

average1 :: IO ()
average1 =
    do
        putStrLn "Enter Marks in Form of a List"
        marks <- getLine
        let m = (read marks)::[Int]
        let x = sum' m 
        let avg = (fromIntegral x)/(fromIntegral $ length m)
        if(m==[])
            then
                putStrLn ("empty List")
            else
                putStrLn ("Your Avarage is " ++ (show avg))

sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

i) The type signature of `average1` is incorrect, the function does not return a value

ii) [Edit: this point was incorrect]

iii) the average value is a float, so you need to cast the integer arguments

iv) Your test `if (x/=[])` is the wrong way round and should use `m` not `x`

v) most of your lines are not in the `IO` monad and so should use `let` inside a `do` block

Comment: MacPhail  thanks a lot for your help. The code compiled no problem but i still get a run time error saying     

    `PRO> average1`
    `Enter Marks in Form of a List`
    `[1,2,3]`
    `Your Avarage is` 
    `Program error: Prelude.read: no parse`

Comment: @jwodder @Vivian McPhail got it, thanks for the help you guys provided. you rock!